# Best practice to build JAR w/ gradle and deploy it - with Jenkins

Tags: java, git, jenkins, groovy, build

I have a Java/Groovy project in a Git repository that creates a JAR that provides a REST API.

I want to deploy that project using Jenkins. What is the best practice to do that including adapting configuration to the destination system (f.e. database passwords).

On my local machine I can create a runnable JAR this way:

```
gradle bootRepackage
```

But when using the Jenkins I have to

- `git clone` the repository,
- copy the custom config file into the `src/main/resources` folder
- build the JAR with `gradle` or `gradlew` (must be installed on build server)
- move created JAR to destination server

What's the best practice to do such a deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I implement such deployment for maven project by implementing running http server on target server

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
```

which listen some port (e.g. 8080) 
When Jenkins build project it send artifact  by POST request to my target server endpoint with cURL

```
curl -X POST --form 'jar_local_path=\"%jar_local_path%\"' \
  --form 'file=@\"%jar_src_path%\"' \
  http://targetserver:8080/requests
```

httpserver handle request and put jar artifact to needed directory on this server